# Return number of columns of a certain data type in a matrix

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe, column-types

I have to create a function ncol_type(df, ty) which returns the number of columns in df of type ty.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ncol_type = function(df, ty) {
    for (col_name in names(df)) {
        col_vector_class <- class(df[,col_name])
        c == 0
        if (col_vector_class == ty) {
            c = c + 1
        }
     return(c)
    }
}
```

For example, if I input n_col_type(df, "integer") where the matrix df has two columns of the integer data type, I want the function to return "2".

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: A `matrix` can only hold one type. What you most likely mean is a `dataframe`. Just so you get the terminology right.

Comment: @AndreElrico Thanks Andre. I'll change the tag

Comment: I would use something like `sum(sapply(df,is.interger))` of course you need to dynamically set the "is.class" part in sapply.

Comment: Perhaps not your question, but you can get all types at once with `table(sapply(iris, function(a) class(a)[1]))`. (The `[1]` is a hack to deal with some things that return 2+, such as `class(Sys.time())`.)

Comment: @r2evans Sounds good. Answer below answered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-write your code and simply use `sum` and iterate with `sapply`

```
ncol_type <- function(df, ty){
  sum(sapply(df, function(x) class(x)==ty))
}

ncol_type(iris, "factor")
[1] 1
ncol_type(iris, "numeric")
[1] 4
```

Comment: you may want `ty %in% class(x)` instead of `class(x)==ty` to be more general

Comment: (Repeated here in case readers don't see my comment above or are looking for keywords.) If you have any multi-class columns such as **`POSIXct`** or **`tbl_df`**, this will not work, you'll need the `%in%` trick as Moody_Mudskipper offered.